# Update autoincrement column in SQL server

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a need to change ONE PK value in one row of a table of a SQLSERVER 2005 databsae. The PK is currently auto-incrementing.

One possibility is to temporarily remove the auto-increment from the key, make the modification, and put it back.

The database is in production. Is there a way to safely make this change without taking the DB down?

Why? My customer wants a specific ID for one of the records.

What am I afraid of? I'm afraid of records being added in the DB while I've modified the key, and it somehow messing up an index on another table that uses the field as an FK? Am I nuts?

Comment: Don't forget that any tables which reference this primary key will need to be updated to the new value before you can delete the old row.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Updating doesn't work - you'd have to insert the new record and delete the old one instead...

```
set identity_insert mytable on

insert mytable (myidentitycolumn, someothercolumn) 
select 42, someothercolumn
from mytable
where myidentitycolumn = 1;

delete mytable where myidentitycolumn = 1;

set identity_insert mytable off
```

Comment: matt - you're right.  answer has been updated accordingly, and a +1 to your answer too.

Comment: Just as a warning, make sure the value you want to add is not already in the database. Also if the record with the client's data is already there, then you need to move the related records in any child tables to the new record before deleting the original record. Use Update statements to this.

Answer (score 4):

You can only update via dropping the identity and re-creating it. However, you could also set identity insert ON (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259221(SQL.80).aspx) and insert a new row with the identity val you want, turn ident insert off, then delete the old one. Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 4):

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT yourTable ON

INSERT INTO yourTable (col1, col2, col3)
select newID, col2, col3
FROM yourTable
WHERE currentID = xxx

SET IDENTITY_INSERT yourTable OFF
```

You may want to lock the table to prevent other inserts from failing while IDENTITY_INSERT is on.

EDIT: Well crap, I forgot the obvious bit about deleting the original record.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @counter int
SET @counter = 0
UPDATE #tmp_Users
SET @counter = counter = @counter + 1
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you don't provide any explanation of the code. If this code answers the question, consider adding adding some text explaining the code in your answer. This way, you are far more likely to get more upvotes — and help the questioner learn something new.

Comment: This code doesn't even come close to answering the question. Did you intend this answer for another question?